# Can Interlocked.Increment overflow cause .NET runtime corruption?

Tags: c#, .net, overflow, interlocked

The MSDN documentation for [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> This method handles an overflow condition by wrapping: if *location* = Int32.MaxValue, *location* + 1 = Int32.MinValue. No exception is thrown.

What does “*location* + 1” mean in this context? If `Increment` alters the memory location next to the *location* field, isn't this likely to lead to corruption in the .NET runtime, given that this adjacent location could be anything (object references, class metadata, etc)?

Comment: In this context, `location` is simply the name of an int variable. So saying `location + 1` is just a normal mathematical statement.

Comment: location + 1 is just a mathematical statement. `location = Int32.MaxValue` so location + 1 would overflow to `Int32.MinValue`

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. (I've been reading too much pointer arithmetic.) Thanks to all for the clarification!

Comment: It is a pretty uninspired name, the argument is actually a pointer.  Thus "location".  The *ref* keyword in C# ensures that a pointer is generated at runtime.  The jitter directly translates the method to a single CPU instruction, LOCK XADD for x86 and x64, no runtime corruption can occur.

Comment: I guess the name threw me off, along with the use of `=` to represent equality rather than assignment. I figured that I was probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It just means that if your value you want to increment is already equal to `Int32.MaxValue` and you increment by one, instead of throwing an error, it returns `Int32.MinValue`

That's the same what happens if you do

```
var value = Int32.MaxValue;
value += 1;
```

If you explicitly want an exception to be thrown, use the `checked` keyword

```
var value = Int32.MaxValue;
value = checked(value + 1);
```

Comment: Just to mention that `value = checked(Interlocked.Increment(ref value));` does **not** throw an exception if value is int.MaxValue, it just sets it to int.MinValue